# Linked Lists C++, output not showing in display function

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class PersonList
{

private:
    char aName[7];
    int aBribe;
    PersonList *link;

public:
    void addNodes();
    void display();

};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "mylink.h"

void PersonList::addNodes()
{

    PersonList *temp2;

    PersonList* startPtr = new PersonList();
    PersonList* current = new PersonList();


        PersonList *temp = new PersonList();//created the first node on the list
        cout<<"Enter the person's name: ";
        cin>>temp->aName;
        cout<<"Enter the person's contribution: ";
        cin>>temp->aBribe;
        temp->link=NULL;//when i get last node, link will point to null(where am i in list?)

        if(startPtr==NULL)
        {
            startPtr = temp;
            current = startPtr;
        }

        else
        {
            temp2 = startPtr;

            while(temp2->link!=NULL)
                temp2 = temp2->link;
            temp2->link=temp;
        }
    //}
}

void PersonList::display()
{
    PersonList *temp;
    PersonList *startPtr = this;

    temp=startPtr;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->aName<<"\t\t"<<temp->aBribe<<endl;
        temp = temp->link;
    }

}

#include <iostream>
#include "mylink.h"

using namespace std;

int displayMenu (void);
void processChoice(int, PersonList&);

int main()
{
int num;

PersonList myList;


do 
{
num = displayMenu();
if (num != 3)
processChoice(num, myList);
} while (num != 3);

return 0;
}

int displayMenu(void)
{
int choice;
cout << "\nMenu\n";
cout << "==============================\n\n";
cout << "1. Add student to waiting list\n";
cout << "2. View waiting list\n";
cout << "3. Exit program\n\n";
cout << "Please enter choice: ";
cin >> choice;

cin.ignore();
return choice;
}

void processChoice(int choice, PersonList& p)
{

switch(choice)
{
case 1: p.addNodes();
break;
case 2: p.display();
break;
}

}
```

My question is the display function is not displaying name and contribution that I enter.
Im using temp variable as a pointer node to call aName and aBribe.  This goes through the list while it has not reached null.  Nothing shows in output

Comment: what happens when you construct a new `PersonList`? does it call `addNodes()` also addNodes seems to be working on local instances only, not on passed in variables or itself, is this intended??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new list:

```
PersonList *startPtr = new PersonList();
```

and then showing that.  So, naturally it is empty.

You have a similar problem in your addNodes method.  You are adding nodes to a new list, then throwing it away, which is actually a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I put this now PersonList *startPtr;  It saying it startPtr is being used without being initialized.  What is the problem?

Comment: It is hard to be sure without seeing your class definition, but perhaps you want PersonList *startPtr = this;

Comment: here is my class definition  #include <string>

using namespace std;

class PersonList
{

private:
 char aName[7];
 int aBribe;
 PersonList *votePtr;

public:
 void addNodes();
 void display();

};

Comment: You would want to include that in your question.

Comment: I added the class defintion and my test.cpp file

Comment: You seem to be creating a list where votePtr points to the next item in the list, but votePtr is an unusual name for it.  Is that the intent?

Comment: Im sorry it should not be votePtr, it should be PersonList *link;  I changed it in the code in my .h, .cpp files.  I still cant get the output displayed  thanks

Comment: I tried putting PersonList* startPtr = this;  but garbage outputs and the program crashes?  Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: I got it working, I had to create a current object in my display function.  Thanks anyway